# How to check if queue is working

Tags: laravel-5

I need to start a game every 30 seconds, cron job minimum interval is a minute, so I use queue delay to do it

#### app/Jobs/StartGame.php

```
public function handle()
{
    // Start a new issue
    $this->gameService->gameStart();

    // Start new issue after 15 seconds
    $job = (new \App\Jobs\StartGame)->onQueue('start-game')->delay(30);
    dispatch($job);
}
```

And I start first game by console

#### app/Console/Commands/StartGame.php

```
public function handle()
{
    $job = (new \App\Jobs\StartGame)->onQueue('start-game');

    dispatch($job);
}
```

The question is, I want to use cron job to check if the start game queue is running, if not then dispatch, in case of something like server stop for maintenance, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a log of the "start-date" in a file, for example : `data_start.log`

1- every time `gameStart()` is called the content of file (date) is checked, and verified if is between 29sec and 31sec.

2- update the content of file.

example of write :

```
<?php
 $file = "data_start.log";
 $f=fopen($file, 'w');
 fwrite( $f, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n");

?>
```